# primitive roots modulo 125

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My computation shows:

2 and 3 are primitive root modulo 5;

Starting from 2,  searching $2+5k$ that $(2+5k)^4 \not\equiv 1(mod 25)$ I get 20 roots: $2, 12, 17, 22, 27, 37, 42, 47, 52, 62, 67, 72, 77, 87, 92, 97, 102, 112, 117, 122$, i.e. omitting $7,32,57,82,107$.

Starting from $3$, excluding $18,43,68,93,118$ I get another 20 roots: $3,8,13,23,28,33,38,48,53,58,63,73,78,83,88,98,103,108,113,123$.

So there are totally 40 primitive roots modulo $125$, am i right?

Comment: There should be $\varphi(\varphi(125))$ primitive roots, by general theorems. [I didn't check what that is, but that would be straightforward.]

Comment: @coffeemath ha test passed, $\varphi(125) = 125 - 25 = 100$, while $\varphi(100)=40$

Comment: athos-- Yeah, did that computation later. Didn't check all 20. One thing is, if you have primitive root $3$ can get the others by raising $3$ to each power beyond $1$ which is coprime to $40,$ then reduce these powers mod $125.$

Comment: @coffeemath I don’t follow that. Suppose I raise $3$ to power $2$, getting $9$ — but $9$ is not a primitive root of $125$?

Comment: @athos use an exponent that is **relatively prime to 40**.

Comment: @OscarLanzi ah I see.. thx!